# fetch dashboard count from database using php jquery ajax

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, dashboard

I'm trying fetch data count from database to HTML `div` using PHP, jQuery and AJAX, but code below is not working.

I just started learning ajax please help. Thank you!

[image]

**index.php**

```
            <div class='col-lg-3 col-md-6'>
                <div class='panel panel-primary'>
                    <div class='panel-heading'>
                        <div class='row'>
                            <div class='col-xs-3'>
                                <i class='fa fa-microphone fa-5x'></i>
                            </div>
                            <div class='col-xs-9 text-right'>
                                            <!-- here i want to fetch result -->
                                            <div id="leadmonth"></div>
                                <div>Total Leads</div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

**Jquery**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

        $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            url:'php_action/resourceqareportdashboardcount.php',
            dataType : 'json',
            success:function(html){
                $('#leadmonth').html(html);
            }

});
```

**PHP**

```
<?php
// This Month Count
require_once 'db_config.php';
$output= '';
$sql = "SELECT * FROM leads WHERE YEAR(leadcreationdate) = YEAR(NOW()) AND MONTH(leadcreationdate)=MONTH(NOW())";
$query = $connect->query($sql);
$totalleads = mysqli_num_rows($query);

        if ($monthtotalleadscount > "0") {
            $output = "<div class='huge'>$totalleads</div>";
        } else {
            $output =  "<div class='huge'>0</div>";
        }

// database connection close
$connect->close();

echo json_encode($output);
```

Comment: When you've open up your `console` window in the 'browser` you've used and check the `Network` section / tab, Did you get a certain message / result from the given ajax url?

Comment: *How* is it not working? Describe your issue! What is working? What isn't?
 What's currently happening, and what do aim to happen? Did you enable error-reporting, and check your logs for errors (PHP) and the console (for JavaScript errors)?

Comment: @eeya yes there is one error in browser > console > Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected end of input

Comment: Done...made some small changes in jquery and problem solved... Now updating answer... Thank You @eeya I didnt know that we can check errors in browser console...  i am not a developer just learning all this from internet only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function() {

        $.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            url:'php_action/resourceqareportdashboardcount.php',
            // dataType : 'json',
            success:function(html){
                $('#totalleadsmonth').html(html);
            }
            });

});
```